# how to use buttons in tab layout in android and use this button to call different fragments and place the tab layout at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, screens

I want to place buttons in a tab layout and use these buttons to call different fragments in a tab layout. Moreover I want to place some image in each button .Can anyone please help ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageButton in your xml file and align it to the bottom of the page and set the text and back image of the ImageButton from code section.
somthing like this:

the_xmlLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/theImageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And somthing like this in your java code:

```
View v = (View) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout., null);
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.theImageButton);
ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.X);
```

You cand define a method to change the background randomly with setBackgroundResource method.